# Maven vs. Eclipse Project Facets for Java EE 6

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, facet

I have created Maven projects inside Eclipse with these archetypes:

- ejb-javaee6
- webapp-javaee6

The projects were created without facets.

**Does it make sense to convert such Maven projects into faceted form?**

**Which facets would be helpful and which ones could cause trouble for a Maven project?**

Specifically: Would any of the following project facets be in conflict with something that is in the responsibility of Maven?

- Java
- JavaScript
- EJB Module
- Dynamic Web Module
- GlassFish Deployment Descriptors Files
- JavaServer Faces

I have the impression that converting a Maven project to faceted form would mean mixing two worlds. Therefore I tend to NOT enable ANY project facets.

But where I work we have examples of Maven projects that are in faceted form and I was wondering whether there might be (risk-free) benefits to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eclipse facets and maven archetypes are orthogonal - i.e. they have no influence on each other, or rather no knowledge of each other. You can safely add the facets if it will facilitate your work with eclipse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have accepted it, as it is the truth at least in theory

Comment: In practical use I found the integration of Maven with m2e rather brittle. For example, the m2e plugin insists on enforcing Java 1.6 although I am using GlassFish that CAN deal with Java 1.7 EJBs. With pure Maven there is absolutely no problem to build, package and deploy (manually).

I tried the same with NetBeans and it worked smoothly, out of the box. I have found Maven integration in NetBeans to be much better for EJB projects.

Comment: @StaticNoiseLog You're welcome. You're right about m2e. I have given it up a while ago in favor of command-line maven and found it more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting I think I have something that works (except that I cannot get m2e to accept Java 1.7 for EJBs).

**Versions:**

- Eclipse Juno 4.2
- m2e 1.3.1
- GlassFish 3.1.2
- JDK 1.7.0_17 (Oracle)

**IMPORTANT USAGE NOTE:** With the setup below, you should disable automatic publishing to GlassFish ("Never publish automatically") *if you want to run Maven clean & install*. For the usual editing and saving work in Eclipse, automatic publishing can be enabled and seems to work fine. Only when starting Maven explicitly (inside Eclipse) did I encounter problems.

**Setting up an EJB project with Maven in Eclipse**

```
Create Maven projects in Eclipse with these archetypes:
 ejb-javaee6
 ear-javaee6
 webapp-javaee6

webapp-javaee6
--------------
- Convert to faceted form, select GlassFish in Runtimes and enable:
  - Dynamic Web Module
  - GlassFish Deployment Descriptors Files
  - Java
  - JavaScript
  - JavaServer Faces
  Further configuration available...
  - Content directory: src/main/webapp
  - NOT checked: Generate web.xml deployment descriptor
  - JSF Capabilities (all defaults): JSF 2.1 + PrimeFaces selected
    CHECKED: "Include libraries with this application"

ejb-javaee6
-----------
- Convert to faceted form, select GlassFish in Runtimes and enable:
  - EJB Module
  - GlassFish Deployment Descriptors Files
  - Java
  Further configuration available...
  - NOT checked: Generate ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor

ear-javaee6
-----------
- Convert to faceted form, select GlassFish in Runtimes and enable:
  - EAR
  - GlassFish Deployment Descriptors Files
  Further configuration available...
  - Add EJB and WEB projects as dependencies
  - Content directory: src/main/application (META-INF location used by Maven)
  - NOT checked: Generate application.xml deployment descriptor
```